# How to gather torrent stats based on tracker?

Tags: php, bittorrent

Having read the torrent specification over and over, I'm still having troubles gathering the number of peers (say, seeds and leechs)from a [BitTorrent] tracker using PHP.

Having access to the server is no problem at all. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Specification here: http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP.2FHTTPS_Protocol

Comment: Can you link us to the specification?

Answer (score 1):

This maybe of some help:

> [PHPBTTracker+](http://phpbttrkplus.sourceforge.net/) is a bittorrent tracker; it is an extension of the original [PHPBTTracker](http://dehacked.2y.net/BT/) authored by DeHackEd.